# Halacha of not biting into a sandwich when someone else is eating with you

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, eating, derech-eretz-manners

I have heard several times (including [here](https://youtu.be/5BIXRo-P_24?list=PL1R4vEmVBZSx0tBpn2kcBDwQkA7g4Ccyo&t=226)) of a halacha (I believe I heard it is mentioned in a gemara) that discusses not taking a bite out of a sandwich when eating with others, as it may make them feel sick and end up choking. Instead, one should tear off a piece of the sandwich and put the whole piece in one's mouth.

Where is this gemara? I seek it because I would like to know if this is halacha, and learn more about this topic, thank you.

Comment: Not sure, but the only relevant thing I found was a Tosfos that says eating bread on street is exceptionally demeaning (תוס' ד"ה ויש)

Comment: These halachot are summarized in [KSA 42:1 and ff](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.42.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) but I didn't find what you are reporting. Shmosel's answer is the closest and it is very likely what you heard is a deformation of that halacha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about the choking, but it says clearly in Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim [170:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.10?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) that one should not bite into food and put it back down, and the commentaries say that's because it's disgusting.

> לא ישוך פרוסה ויניחנה על גבי השלחן

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't match what I've heard _exactly_ so I will wait for more answers and do more research before accepting

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may actually be a different סעיף in סימן קע, in [סעיף ז](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.170.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it says לא יאכל אדם פרוסה כביצה ואם אכל (הרי) זה גרגרן, one should not eat a piece the size of an egg, and on this the מגן אברהם comments: לא יאכל. פי' שלא יאחזנו בידו אף על פי שאינו אוכלו בבת אחת (ב"י), that this is referring to holding such a size piece in his hand even though his isn't eating it at once.

[Here](https://halacha2go.com/?number=135) is an online shiur discussing this from this source.